# Is there a way to update MobileConnect Subscription Data from a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, subscriber

I have noticed a sizeable chunk of data imported into MobileConnect has an incorrect Opt-in and Opt-out status.

I would like to correct the data, but don't want to do so manually on thousands of records. How can one update fields already in specifically in MobileConnect Subscription Data (and not in MobileConnect Demographics).

I intended to do so with queries or import definitions, but it would seem one cannot target _MobileSubscription.

Does anyone have any exprience with editing existing Mobile Subscription data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to contact builder => import, you can create an import that can import subscribers from a data extension to a keyword, and then set their correct status based by a column's value in the DE.

You need one data extension and import definition per keyword.

Note, the subscription is BU specific.

** UPDATE **

If a person has opt'ed out, they need to update their status by either opt'ing in with an actual SMS or you need to update their status using an API call

Comment: Hitting the issue with the out->in update. Which API are you using Kenneth? The Contact Attributes or Mobile Connect?

Comment: If memory serves, You need to update the mobile connect all subscribers list :)

Comment: Hmm thats only the general opt in not the keyword so if all keywords are opt out you still cannot even if the general is opt in.

Comment: Sorry, might be confusing things - there are two scenarios right? I opt out from the account or i opt in to the keyword. Keyword based opt in. I believe One from my team has solved it using ampscript in an e-mail that confirms the mobile opt in, which basically re-subscribes you to the keyword. Believe It’s mobile connect api :)

Comment: Hmm.. Yea it seems API is the only reliable way :( We looked at this, having the MobileConnect Demographic data updated from SFDC, but creating it only works using singular contacts (not batch) so would be a massive drag on performance for our volumes :( 
Once the contact is there, we can do mass subscription using attribute set REST Methods but you need to extract the Keyword GUID, which can only be done based on the GET Attributes method, because no where on the interface or via API is it else visible :( ..another "come on, salesforce" moment it seems :(

Comment: @kenneth Wagner do you have a sample API call to update the Mobile connect subscriber status?

Comment: Afraid not Chandan, but should be accessible either here or via help documents

Answer (score 5):

That is correct, opt-in can only be done manually, or opt-in from mobile or via API.

Opt-out can be done via Import in Mobile - All contact and populate the Status field with the value Unsubscribe (MobileConnect Demographics).