# Update Mobile Connect SMS Opt In/Opt Out status with imports to MobileSubscription

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, subscriber

My client has their own LOPD legalese database, and they want to update the standard logic that Marketing Cloud has when a subscriber perform an SMS Opt-in/Opt-out.

The solution to implement that is to generate an import activity that update the subscriber status to a data extension named "Mobile Connect Subscription". Marketing Cloud offer the solution to import data to "Mobile Connect Demograpics", but not the possibility to import Opt-in/out statuses.

Does anyone know if is possible to generate an import activity in order to update this data extension which contains the subscriber membership?

Here is the way of getting data views from this data extension:[How to bulk export MobileConnect SMS subscriptions?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions)

So, the idea is to import that data updated in this system data extension to perform a custom SMS opt in/out process.

This post is very similar but the solution provided by @Kenneth Wagner is not enough clear. I´m triying to talk with him to clarify the issue: [Is there a way to update MobileConnect Subscription Data from a Data Extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164462/is-there-a-way-to-update-mobileconnect-subscription-data-from-a-data-extension)

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opt-out can be done via Import in Mobile - All contacts and populate the Status field with the value Unsubscribe (MobileConnect Demographics). So this is a update from opt-in to opt-out. Opt-out to opt-out can not be done via import.

API
Manually
or Mobile opt-in through phone.

Comment: Take into account that "Status" type of field is Numeric, so the value "unsubscribe" which is correct for All Subscriber list, do not work out in this case. 

I've seen that "Sforce" said yesterday there is a pre-defined codes in this case for "status" field, but is always as "Active" instead of changing the status. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions?rq=1

Comment: I've tried to use REST API calls to update the status but I'm having always the same error. "errors": ["An unexpected error occurred, please contact Customer Support with reference id M3pVMU45M25EVWkyalVwQW9Qb0ZyZzo3Njow"]}"

Comment: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/contacts/import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_all_contacts/prepare_file_for_import/

This exactly tells you how to import for unsubscribe, works perfectly. Numeric value is not necessary.

Comment: I've tried again your suggestion, and it worked out! So, we can conclude that the value "Unsubscribe"  for status field can Opt-out the contact. Thanks a lot!