# Update MobileConnect Demographics from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, import

I seem unable to update an existing row in MobileConnect All Contacts list.

I also seem to not be the only one with the confusion:

[Is there a way to update MobileConnect Subscription Data from a Data Extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164462/is-there-a-way-to-update-mobileconnect-subscription-data-from-a-data-extension)
[How do I update mobile connect demographics when data for a contact changes?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DiRlQAK)

My account seems to be set up correctly based on [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gWhQAI) known issue.

I have a single row in a source Data Extension:

[image: Source DE]

And an Import Definition like so:

[image: Import Definition]
[image: Import Definition Mapping]

Which points to the source DE. The Contact Key field on the row in the source DE matches a Contact Key in the All Contacts list. I would expect it to then update the mobile contact with the new values but it does not. I.e., I would expect the highlighted fields (see below image) to now include the boolean values as seen in the source DE:

[image: MobileConnect Contact]

Contact builder looks like so:

[image: Contact Builder]

Question is what am I missing here? Is Contact Key not the correct upsert key? I also see a field called Contact ID - is this instead it?

Edit: I am getting the following notification email with validation errors from SFMC:

"The following import has completed with validation errors" and the csv says required field _mobileNumber although the Mobile Number in my import is not empty:

Row Number  Error Number    Error Code  Error Details   Row Data
0   133273946   RequiredField   _MobileNumber   [34805][1234567890][1234567890][DK][Test][Test][False][True]

Comment: I am just taking a guess here. Can you see all the mobile connect demographics Attribute group linked to the contact key in Contact Builder->Data Designer?

Comment: Another guess, have you tried with 1/0 values for true/false?

Comment: @PraveenKumarBandi - I updated the post so you can see the Data Designer

Comment: @SebOB - Do you mean changing the Source DE to have numeric fields instead of t/f?

Comment: @rzr, I think the mobile number field on your DE should be of  type "Phone" not text

Comment: @PraveenKumarBandi - It already is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check you mapping in the import definition. On some occasions, the "Map by Header Row" is failing. Even though the mapping looks correctly in the UI, it fails to map the fields properly. Switching it to "Map Manually", even though it is the exact same mapping, sometimes solves the issue.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.

Comment: I encountered the same issue just today, and this simple fix did the trick. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You are welcome, @PhilipW - remember to upvote, when an answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you are receiving, I would believe you should add the following to your import Data Extension:

- Priority (which should just have default value of 1)
- Mobile Number needs to be written as 4512345678 (i.e. 10 digits), even though you have proper locale
- Ensure Field Lengths are equal to each other (or that the DE isn't longer than target fields in Mobile Demographics)

Hope it helps