# Mobile Connect Import

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am trying to subscribe back the contacts in Mobile Connect who have status as 'Not Opted in' through a csv file. However, the import says 'Invalid Context Status'. Does this mean that we cannot update a mobile subscriber's opt in status through import file?

Comment: SFMC doesn't allow you to re-optin contacts in bulk as a guardrail

Comment: Thanks @EazyE . Just to confirm, this is only the case in MobileConnect right, because I am opting in subscribers in email studio(All Subscribers)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you cannot opt-in via bulk import when contact is opted-out.

The only way to opt them back in is via SMS or via API.

ref: ([Is there a way to update MobileConnect Subscription Data from a Data Extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164462/is-there-a-way-to-update-mobileconnect-subscription-data-from-a-data-extension))

API call Example:

```
PATCH /contacts/v1/contacts
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}

{
   "contactKey":"1234",
   "attributeSets": [{
         "name":"MobileConnect Subscriptions",
         "items": [{
               "values": [
                     { "name":"Keyword", "value":"XXXXXXXXX" },
                     { "name":"Mobile Number", "value":"15558675309" },
                     { "name":"Opt In Status", "value":1 },
                     { "name":"Opt Out Status", "value":0 }
               ]
         }]
   }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I am aware of the API method, However, this triggers a confirmation SMS to the end user. I was trying to avoid that

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, I have used the queueMO api  till now, I used the above api that you mentioned, but it gives me : 
            "message": "Update failed for one or more AttributeSets. Note: Updates aren't allowed on attributes that form the primary Key of the attributeset"

Answer (score 0):

to resub via QUEUEMO, so long as the sub count is not massive, (If you do this for more then 25k records you will likely get a reverse escalation) you can toss and IF/ELSE ampscript argument in the message body. If you know the mobile numbers on the individuals you need to resub and run your statement against a DE of these phone numbers, you need to set the message copy to %%[]%%

This will silently subscribe a user to the keyword you need and flip their status back to active.